# How to connect points to only nearby points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, points-to-line

I have points for addresses and points for facades of the buildings in which the address lies. I dont have a buildings polygon shapefile. How can I connect each address point with only the facade points of that building? An example is attached in the image. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'connect'? Create lines? Add the building ID to the attributes of the corresponding facade points?

Comment: Actually add a facade point attribute (noise) to the address point and then check what is the max noise value (among all the facade points that surround it) for that address point.

Comment: With [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) you can join attributes of the closest facade point to the attributes of the building point. If you want to join all facade points to the corresponding building point, more information about your data is needed (is there any useful attribute that can be used, are buildings close to each other so that a facade point could be assigned to the wrong building, etc)

Comment: I want to join all facade points to the corresponding building point. There is no useful attribute as such that would help to make this join. The facade points just have noise values and the building points have an ID. The buildings are fairly close to each other like they would be in any urban area so yes if we talk about connecting with distances then there is a chance of being assigned to the wrong building. The only helpful thing to know is the facade points always surround the corresponding building point like in the image above.

Comment: Do the facade Points of a certain building have some common attribute? Something that can be used to identify a group?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Were they created one builing at a time so that for example point 1-10 is one building, 11-25 is next building and so on?

Comment: Are all buildings located on separate cadastral lots? If so, do you have access to cadastral data for the area you're working in?

Answer (score 1):

It is scripting free approach to go from this:
[image]
to this:
[image]

Providing that distance between your noise points is **smaller (!)** than distance between buildings.
Let me know if this is the case and I'll post the workflow.

Comment: I just checked. Dont think the distance between noise points is always smaller than the distance between buildings.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @GISGe use [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) with Facade Points as target feature and Building/Adress Points as join features. Use match option Closest and perhaps a search radius.

> Joins attributes from one feature to another based on the spatial
>   relationship. The target features and the joined attributes from the
>   join features are written to the output feature class.

[image]

[image]

This will not work if you have a situation like below. Some facade Points will get the wrong adress.

[image]

Comment: But then there is every possibility that the false building point will be assigned to the facade points because not everywhere are the building points exactly in the center of the building. So probably a building point which belongs to the neigbouring building will be assigned to the facade point when that building point is in a corner of its buidling and closer to the facade point of our building.

Comment: Just saw the picture. yes I have the same situation in many cases.

Comment: In that case i belive you need to get a hold of a dataset of building polygons.

Comment: Yes I have already asked my collegue to acquire this dataset (for which we need to pay). I was just wondering if there was another way without it.